# Enabling my jstl fmt messages

Tags: java, properties, jstl, message

I've got a properties file in my classpath with items like the following

```
PI20=Fältet "Ankomstdatum tom" har datumformatet åååå-mm-dd eller ååååmmdd. # AF Sök
PI61=Sökresultatet är exporterat. # AF Sök
PI3000=Rapporter och uppdragshandlingar till Varumärkeseneheten finns på << 1 >>. Rapporter och uppdragshandlingar till Designeneheten finns på << 2 >>. # AF Registrera uppdrag
```

In my JSP I do this

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jstl/fmt" prefix="fmt"%>
<fmt:setBundle basename="messages.properties"/>
<fmt:message key="PI61"/>
```

but my message does not appear. How can I enable my messages according to use for the fmt tag?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not include `.properties` in [`basename`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/fmt/setBundle.html); and assuming that `messages.properties` is located at the root of classpath.